# Отмена кнопки win

Tags: javascript

Разрабатываю биткоин кран. Там пользователь сначала должен кликнут на рекламу потом получить за это сатоши. Реклама находится внутри `iframe`. Мне нужно узнать сделал ли клик на рекламу пользователь. Захватываю клик с помощью `iframeTracker`, но `iframeTracker` реагирует не только на ЛК мыши, но и на ПК мыши и на кнопки <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>win</kbd>. Кнопки <kbd>Tab</kbd> и <kbd>Alt</kbd> просто отменил так:

```js
var cancelKeypress = false;

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    cancelKeypress = /^(9|18|91|92|93)$/.test("" + evt.keyCode);
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

/* For Opera */
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    if (cancelKeypress) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Но клавиши 91, 92 (кнопки <kbd>win</kbd>) не отменяются. Как можно отменить нажатие кнопки <kbd>win</kbd>?

Comment: И правая кнопка отменяется только на странице а не во фрейме

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` не может остановить действие по нажатию на кнопку <kbd>win</kbd>. Это то, что происходит за пределами контекста браузера и, следовательно, не может и не должно блокироваться кодом, запущенным в вашем браузере.

Лучше всего ловить в коде данное событие и вызывать нужную вам функцию/обработку данного события:

```js
    $(window).keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 91) {
        //Ваша обработка при нажатии на кнопку Win
        alert('Кнопка Win была нажата!');
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А почему вообще iframeTracker реагирует на кнопки win, правая кнопка мыши? Нельзя ли в коде исправить это дело, чтобы среагировало только на ЛК мыши? Вот код iframeTracker: https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.iframetracker.js